# Data Studio Community Connector: Adding a tree hierarchy in the Config section

Tags: looker-studio

How does the Google Analytics connector add the hierarchical options tree to select which dataset to use? Is it a custom control?

We have the same need right now, where we want the user to choose multiple items, with database->Node->Item tree of over 20000 items. Ideally we would also like to search for elements.

In tableau, you implement a html page with js backing, so you can put any controls you want in this section, but the Data Studio seems to have just it's own subset.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated, as this is a blocker in using the Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Data Studio Community Connectors, dynamic or hierarchical config is not supported yet. For now, you can either provide a flat list or a type in option.

If you require searchable options and hierarchical configs, please put in feature requests / vote for them [in the issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:321382).

Edit: Updated link.